# XML parsing to Java Object List<Map<String,String>> sqlParams;

Tags: java, xml

In one of my projects i have a scenario where I'll be getting a xml file which contain sql parametrs, I have to read and construct Java object from that.

Below is sample xml

```
<parameters>
    <sql id="1">
        <city>Chennai</city>
        <state>Tamilnadu</state>
    </sql>
    <sql id="2">
        <city>Mumbai</city>
        <state>Maharashtra</state>
    </sql>
    <sql id="3">
        <city>Kolkata</city>
        <state>West Bengal</state>
    </sql>
</parameters>
```

I have to parse and get keys and values from these xml.
The Java object I'm expecting is

```
List<Map<String,String>> sqlParams;
Map sqlOne; sqlOne.put(city,Chennai); sqlOne.put(state,Tamilnadu); sqlParams.add(sqlOne);
Map sqlTwo; sqlTwo.put(city,Mumbai); sqlTwo.put(state,Maharashtra); sqlParams.add(sqlTwo);
```

and so on...

We use this List of map to run SQL.
Can some one suggest me a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To parse xml in java object, you can look into this documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

a very fast and convenient way of mapping XML is to use some existing library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml).
It's usage is quite simple. You write a plain object class like the example:

```
public class Simple {
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 2;
}
```

which maps a structure like this:

```
<Simple>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
</Simple>
```

After installing the library you it's intuitive how to map your data structure.
I would recommend for your next projects to use a some project management tools (like maven or gradle) which allows you to easily import libraries for such tasks and to spend some time to investigate how database querying is implemented around. You might have a look to spring JPA just as a starting point.